# How SQL Server Engine work for this join scenario?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2019 and while optimization i found that on condition of join is placed in different way as below,

```
SELECT * 
FROM #table1 a 
INNER JOIN dbo.table2 b 
INNER JOIN dbo.table3 c ON c.id = b.id 
                        ON b.id=a.id
```

How this join actually work by SQL Server engine ?
After changing this join to as below, sql server returns similar returns,

```
   SELECT * 
    FROM #table1 a 
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 b ON b.id=a.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.table3 c ON c.id = b.id
```

Could you please help me to understand whether these two queries work as same way or not? if not then how first query is different from second query?

Comment: The first query between the #table1 and table2 performs a CROSS JOIN, each row of #table1 is joined with each row of table2. [See this](https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-cross-join-with-examples/)

Comment: @Max - no, it doesn't. It performs a `INNER JOIN` exactly as it says. The difference is that that join is computed *after* the other join.

Comment: In this circumstance, with just `INNER JOIN` and each `ON` clause only referencing two tables, the logical results are identical.

Comment: Normally the former syntax makes more sense when the first join is a `LEFT JOIN`; there's really no need for the confusing syntax with just `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're right, I read fast I don't notice the 2nd `b.id = a.id`. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically, the queries are equivalent, in this situation.

In the first, the join between `b` and `c` using `ON c.id = b.id` is (logically) computed. Note that `a` isn't in scope in this `ON` clause. Lets call that result `bc`.

*Then*, the join between `a` and `bc` is computed using `ON b.id=a.id`<sup>1</sup>. Note that this second `ON` clause *could* have also referenced `c`.

The position of the `ON` clauses is changing the order in which the `JOIN`s are computed, which makes no difference for `INNER JOIN`s.

The second query is more straightforward to read since each `JOIN` is appearing in the same order in which they are computed.

If the first join was instead a `LEFT JOIN` then you could start to see differences between the two queries, due to the different join order.

---

<sup>1</sup>I often use the analogy of parentheses here - to find what order `JOIN`s are computed in, you need to find their corresponding `ON` clause. If you treat each `JOIN` as `(` and each `ON` as `)`, then matching parenthesis indicate which `JOIN` and `ON` clauses match up.